# docker container (flask + mariadb) works and then crashes with error "2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db:3306' (111 Connection refused)"

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-compose, mariadb

I am quite surprised with my docker container behavior. I have a flask app with a mariadb database. It has no issue outside the container, on my local machine. More puzzling, sometimes the `docker compose up` works just fine while sometimes it crashes.
Usually chrashes happen when I have already done `docker compose up` at least once, stopped and removed the containers `app` and `db` and re-execute `docker compose up` and they come with error :

`mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db:3306' (111 Connection refused)`

Here is my `docker-compose.yml` (I have removed all the `networks:` blocks and now use the compose default network instead but the problem remains the same, sometimes it works and sometimes not)

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
    app:
        build: .
        depends_on:
            - db
        environment:
            - DB_HOST=db
            - DB_USER=root
            - DB_PASSWORD=$DB_PASSWORD
            - DB=Catach
        ports:
            - 5000:5000
        volumes:
            - ./caisse:/src
    db:
        image: mariadb:latest
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$DB_PASSWORD
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=Catach
        volumes:
            - mariadb_data:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
    mariadb_data:
        driver: local
```

and my DB_PASSWORD is in a `.env` file at the same location of my `.yml` :

```
DB_PASSWORD="mypassword"
```

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3-alpine

COPY caisse/ /src
RUN pip install -r /src/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /src
CMD ["python3", "app.py"]
```

Eventually, here is my mariadb database connection from my `app.py`

```py
from flask import Flask, url_for, render_template, request, flash, redirect, send_file
import mysql.connector as mariadb
import os
import datetime
from xlsxwriter import Workbook
from utils import export_db

#Paramètres de connexion MariaDB
mariadb_host = os.environ.get('DB_HOST')
mariadb_user = os.environ.get('DB_USER')
mariadb_pwd = os.environ.get('DB_PASSWORD')
mariadb_db = os.environ.get('DB')

#Connection (et création si nécessaire) de la base de données
app_db = mariadb.connect(host=mariadb_host, user=mariadb_user, password=mariadb_pwd)
```

I have searched through many of the existing threads but most of the issues were that the host `db` was not correctly specified, which I think I did.

I also have tried to remove containers of my app image, repulling mariadb image etc. I can't figure out any pattern on when the error occurs or when it doesn't. It seems that when removing my application image with `docker rmi`, it works "more often" but it is not robust though since sometimes I did remove the image and rebuild it with my `docker compose up` and still having the same error.

Any insights or ideas where does the problem may come from ?

Comment: It sounds like a timing issue to me. The database needs some time to be ready to accept connections. `depends_on` only waits for the database container to be started. Not for it to be ready.

Comment: If you run `docker-compose up -d`, it fails the first time, but reliably works the second time, that's also a sign of the timing issue @HansKilian mentions.  `docker-compose up` without `-d` will show database-initialization messages after the application fails as well.  If this is your problem, see [Docker Compose wait for container X before starting Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746182/docker-compose-wait-for-container-x-before-starting-y) for a couple of approaches to it.

Comment: thanks for your comments, it indeed solved the puzzle :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [@Hans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3924803/hans-kilian) and [@David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10008173/david-maze)'s comment, I solved this using docker compose healthchecks

Here is my `docker-compose.yml` now, the rest remains unchanged :

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
   app:
       build: .
       depends_on:
           db:
               condition: service_healthy
       environment:
           - DB_HOST=db
           - DB_USER=root
           - DB_PASSWORD=$DB_PASSWORD
           - DB=Catach
       ports:
           - 5000:5000
       volumes:
           - ./caisse:/src
   db:
       image: mariadb:latest
       environment:
           - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$DB_PASSWORD
           - MYSQL_DATABASE=Catach
       volumes:
           - mariadb_data:/var/lib/mysql
       healthcheck:
           test: "mariadb $$MYSQL_DATABASE -uroot -p$$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD -e 'SELECT 1;'"
           interval: 2s
           timeout: 2s
           retries: 10

volumes:
   mariadb_data:
       driver: local
```